# Initialize an interface in an Activity

Tags: java, android

How can I initialize an interface in the MainActivity?
I have tried it like the following, but it keeps giving error.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MainActivity");

    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    private ExpandableListViewAdapter mExpandableListViewAdapter;
    private List<String> mListDataGroup;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> mListDataChild;
    PreselectionAplicationUseCases preselectionAplicationUseCases;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
        initListeners();
        initObjects();
        initListData();

        preselectionAplicationUseCases=(PreselectionAplicationUseCases) this;
   }
```

Interface:

```
public interface PreselectionAplicationUseCases {
        void setOnMsgPreselectionChanged(MSG0100.OnMsg100PreselectionChanged listener);
        void setMsg100PreselectionAplication(boolean msg100PreselectionAplication);
    }
```

Errors:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: game, PID: 18315
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{game/game.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: game.MainActivity cannot be cast to game.usecases.PreselectionAplicationUseCases
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5271)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: game.MainActivity cannot be cast to game.usecases.PreselectionAplicationUseCases
        at game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5271) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Comment: I couldn't see   PreselectionAplicationUseCases can be assigned from MainActivity.. so the exception seems fine..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:   `preselectionAplicationUseCases=(PreselectionAplicationUseCases) this;`

You cannot cast MainActivity to PreselectionAplicationUseCases since MainActivity or any of it's superclasses don't extend PreselectionAplicationUseCases.